# JNI How to concatenate two string arrays in C++ native function

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm going to use JNI to implement C++ native function that receives two string arrays, concatenate them into one string array, and return the big string array.
Actually, I'm going to extend [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584864/jni-how-to-concatenate-two-int-arrays-in-c-native-function) to string arrays. 
How can I complete the following codes?

Java side code:

```
String [] strarrayA={"abc", "def"}, strarrayB = {"123","456"};
String[] strarrayC = strarrayFromJNI(strarrayA, strarrayB);

public native String[] strarrayFromJNI(String[] first, String[] second);
```

Native side code:

```
jarray
Java_com_androidMexample_MainActivity_strarrayFromJNI(
    JNIEnv *env, jobject /* this */, jarray a, jarray b){

    jsize alen = env->GetArrayLength(a);
    jsize blen = env->GetArrayLength(b);

    ...
    (How can I concatenate a and b to obtain c, result <- a, b ?)

    return c;
}
```

How can I obtain the returned string array with strarrayC = {"abc", "def", "123", "456"}? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely have to, it could go like this:

```
jobjectArray ab = env->NewObjectArray(alen+blen, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), 0);
jsize i;
for(i=0;i<alen;i++)
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(ab, i, env->GetObjectArrayElement(a, i));
for(i=0;i<blen;i++)
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(ab, alen+i, env->GetObjectArrayElement(b, i));
```

But you could do the same in Java. It won't be noticeably slower, but much easier to read and understand.

Comment: Thanks Seva, it works perfect.  In my code,  I replaced "jarray" with "jobjectArray."